# Can low end hepa vaccums still clean near all of the air?

Tags: vacuum, air

In the US HEPA filters will remove 99.97% of particles sized 0.3 microns.  In Europe HEPA filters do not have to meet this exact figure and there are different classes of HEPA filters e.g. h10(removes 85% at .3 microns, h11 removes 95% at .3 microns etc, h14 removes 99.97% etc.).

Suppose you have a vacuum cleaner that is h10(removes 85% of particles at .3 microns), when vacuuming 15% of .3 microns will pass through the filter.  If we continue to vacuum the area these will go into the vacuum again and be filtered again.  Therefore even though the filter performs less, is it correct to say eventually(with continued vacuuming) the filter will remove the remaining 15% so its not a big deal if you get one with 85% or 99.9% filtration so long as you are bothered to continue vacuuming?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Particles that small do not fall immediately to the ground so that you can vacuum them up again.  According to [this presentation](http://www.cdc.gov/niosh/topics/aerosols/pdfs/aerosol_101.pdf) the settling time for $0.3\ \mu\text{m}$ particles is longer than 41 hours in still air.

The reason for a HEPA filter on a vacuum (which is the last filtration stage) is to clean the fine particles so that you don't inject them into the air where they can be inhaled, causing allergy and respiratory problems.